# Angular2 @angular/material unmet dependency

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

I have installed angular2 material from npm. Now I want to install another package, but it gives error

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.0.2 wants @angular/common@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/material@2.0.0-alpha.9-3 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.2 wants @angular/common@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.2 wants @angular/common@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.2 wants @angular/common@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/common@2.1.0
```

I am using the last version of `@angular/material`, however it depends on `@angular/common@^2.0.0`. What should I do in order to fix conflicts and use these packages?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "materialdesign",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "watchman": "^0.1.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your @angular/common version? You can check it in packages.json file.

Comment: I updated the question with package.json.

Comment: `npm install --save @angular/common@2.0.2` try installing with version included.

Comment: It gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a dependency resolution issue; I had a similar problem that was fixed with these steps:

1. Upgrade to the [latest NodeJS version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)
2. `npm --version` and make sure it's `3.10.x`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm rebuild`

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül I added a bit to my answer. If you still face the problem, tell me: what do you see when you do `npm --version`? What about `node --version`?

Comment: npm 2.15.9, node v4.6.1

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül I rewrote my answer.

Comment: I updated npm and checked its latest version, it shows 3.10.9 https://github.com/npm/npm/releases

Comment: It worked when I updated the npm to 3.10.9. Thanks for your help!